# How to find the MAC address of devices in network path when I do a tracerout?

Tags: networking, network-interface, mac-address, traceroute

**Scenario**:

I am doing traceroute (or any path trace program) from sydney-server1 to london-server2. I can see the route its going with device name and IP address. Is there anyway, I can get those device MAC address too ?

example path :
sydney-server1 --> sydney-router --> Sydney-gateway--> WAN --> london-gateway --> London-router --> London-server2

Can I get the MAC address for these for all these device ? (Using Redhat linux on servers)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no you can't at least not all of them. The only MACs you should be able to see from an end point is your own and all other systems on the switch fabric but not through a gateway. (I'll define a gateway as a router on which its interfaces span multiple subnets not just a router that talks to a modem)

But depending on what access to these systems there's ways you can find out. IPv6 may base its address on the MAC allowing you to find out what it is. If you control all routers or control both endpoints and theres only one router.. etc then you can circumstantially.

Comment: oh okay. noted on that. Will try those as well.

Thanks a lot